# How does mapboxgl handle rendering with different vector data at different zoom?

Tags: three.js, mapbox-gl-js

For example, when rendering buildings, when zoom changes from 5 to 6, are the rendering objects of zoom 5 deleted and then rendered at zoom 6? Will this cause flickering? How does mapboxgl handle preventing flickering?

I want to use threejs to implement something similar to mapboxgl, which loads and displays buildings according to different zoom levels.